# Add item to OHLCSeries choosing whether notifying/firing data changed

Tags: java, notifications, time-series, series, notifydatasetchanged

OHLCSeries 'add' method invokes the ComparableObjectSeries class method 'add', which receives a parameter "notify" to indicate whether you want to notify listeners about the change.

My problem is that OHLCSeries 'add' method doesn't has that parameter, so I can't choose between notifying or not, and I need to be able to.

I've tried invoking the 'super' (ComparableObjectSeries) add method from OHLCSeries, but it is not visible.

Any idea on how could I choose when notify listeners and when not, when adding new items?

(I would like to avoid having to override the entire OHLCSeries class or extend it, hoping there is a easier way of doing it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ComparableObjectSeries extends org.jfree.data.general.Series, I've thought on using this class method 'setNotify()' to activate/deactivate notifications to OHLCSeries listeners before invoking the 'add' method.

Even though this solution makes the trick, I'm still interested on how could it be done using a parameter on the 'add' method, directly from OHLCSeries class, so any idea is welcome.